# How to make code completion for Java 8 lambda parameters in Eclipse work?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

Suppose I have an interface like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ModifierFunction {

    Game applyModifier(Game game, Card card, Modifier modifier);
}
```

and some class where I use it:

```
SHOWDOWN_BUFF((game, card, modifier) -> {
    game. // <- I get no proposals from Eclipse here
    return game;
})
```

My problem is that if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> I can't see `Game`'s methods...in fact I get no proposals at all. It does not work if I use this syntax either:

```
SHOWDOWN_BUFF((Game game, Card card, Modifier modifier) -> {
    game. // <- I get no proposals from Eclipse here either
    return game;
})
```

How can I get code completion to work in Eclipse Luna for Java 8?

**edit**: I'm using *Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)*

Comment: I tried IDEA but it lacks some functions which I use **every day** in Eclipse.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Have you configured your project to use Java 8 compliance and libraries?

Comment: I have java 8 compliance and libraries.

Comment: Uh oh, I’m still waiting for Eclipse’s compiler to become standard-compliant and not failing on type inference all the time, etc. *Then* I may ask for code completion inside lambdas as well…

Comment: I gave up and switched to IntelliJ IDEA. They fixed most of the stuff I did not like back then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter completion within Java 8 Lambda expression works with Eclipse Mars (4.5.0).
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/jdt.php

Comment: This page says nothing about parameter completion within lambda expressions.