# Content Assist not working inside Lambda Expressions

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8, eclipse-jdt

I'm running Mars 4.5.1. Content Assist isn't working at all inside the code blocks of lamba expressions.

```
obj.doSomething(param1 -> {
    // Content Assist doesn't work here
}
```

Anything outside of the code block auto completes fine. Ex: param1 would correctly display content assist.

[It was supposedly fixed in 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071977/how-to-make-code-completion-for-java-8-lambda-parameters-in-eclipse-work), but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

[When I try to manually set 1.8 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544064/java-8-lambdas-dont-work-everything-else-from-java-8-works-though) by unchecking "Use default compliance settings", the box gets re-enabled every time I exit preferences. Compiler compliance level is set at 1.8 to no avail.

Comment: Generally, content assist in lambda body does work in Mars. If it doesn't for you then we probably need more context. If you have a reproducing example please consider filing a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=UI

Comment: Your problem regarding 1.8 compatibility I don't understand. What compliance do you get with / without "Use default compliance settings"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem was known [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481215) that was fixed a long time ago, and the (now ancient) version of Eclipse it occurred in has long since been made obsolete.

Comment: Really? So for those of us who are stuck using the "ancient" version due to compatibility, we just have to deal with it? No patch, no update. Fleh